# What are some models that performs like Linear Discriminant Analysis?

Tags: classification

I am interested in knowing what are some of the models that perform like Linear Discriminant Analysis which takes a combination of variables that best explain the data? I have a data set where some of the predictors are correlated and I want to do classification using this data set.

Comment: Logistic regression (including multinomial one) can be an alternative. There was several posts here comparing the two, so please search LDA logistic on this site, for details.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of explaining or describing the data, both [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) and Factor Analysis are quite similar. They both find linear combinations of variables that describe the data; in the case of PCA, it finds a combination that has the most variance, then another, unrelated combination that has the second most variance.

However, since you mentioned classification, I think you might also be interested in [Logistic Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

Answer (score 0):

Check out linear kernel SVM (liblinear package) or logistic regression (vowpal wabbit package). These should get you started quickly.